# Jest mock document.activeElement

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, jestjs

I have a function that uses the DOM

```js
const trap = {
  // ...
  init() {
    if (document.activeElement === this.firstTabStop) {
      return this.lastTabStop.focus();
    }
  }
}

module.exports = trap.init;
```

I try to mock `document.activeElement` but it throws an error.

```js
global.document.activeElement = mockFirstTabStop;
```

`mockFirstTabStop` is just function mock, but whatever I put there, the error is the same.

> TypeError: Cannot set property activeElement of [object Object] which has only a getter

So, how can I test that conditional to expect `this.lastTabStop.focus()` was called?

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: How can I test that codition? `return this.lastTabStop.focus();`

Comment: You could try and call the focus method of an element to _make_ it the active one.

Comment: @CBroe yh I found a solution to it by mocking the DOM. You can check my own answer for more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to create a mocked DOM and use it as scenario:

**trap.js**

```
const trap = {
  // ...
  init() {
    if (document.activeElement === this.firstTabStop) {
      return this.lastTabStop.focus();
    }
  }
}

module.exports = trap.init;
```

**trap.test.js**

```
const trap = require('./trap.js');

// Mock a DOM to play around
document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div>
        <button id="btn1">btn 1 </button>
        <button id="btn2">btn 2 </button>
        <button id="btn3">btn 3 </button>
    </div>
`;

// Mock Jest function
const mockBtnFocus = jest.fn();
const mockBtnFirst = document.getElementById('btn1');
const mockBtnLast = document.getElementById('btn3');


it('should focus this.lastTabStop when activeElement is this.firstTabStop', () => {
    mockBtnFirst.focus(); // <<< this is what sets document.activeElement
    mockBtnLast.focus = mockBtnFocus;

    // Mock trap context to access `this`
    trap.bind({
        firstTabStop: mockBtnFirst,
        lastTabStop: mockBtnLast,
    });

    expect(mockBtnLast.focus).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution:

```js
const element = document.createElement('div');

Object.defineProperty(document, 'activeElement', { value: element, writable: false });
```